# Add method to parent scope for testing execution an expression in the context of the parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I want to test that external expression will be calling.
But I can not add function to the parent scope. How I can do it?

What patterns or methods exist?

Why fail test `external expression should be calling`?

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('testDir', testDir);

function testDir() {
  return {
    scope: {
      externalExpression: '&'
    },
    template: '<button on-click="externalExpression()">Call external expression</button>'
  }
}

describe('testDir', () => {
  let scope;
  let compile;
  let validHTML;

  function create() {
    var elem, compiledElem;
    elem = angular.element(validHTML);
    compiledElem = compile(elem)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    return compiledElem;
  }
  beforeEach(module("app"));

  beforeEach(
    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      compile = $compile;
    })
  );

  it("should be defined", () => {
    validHTML = "<test-dir></test-dir>";
    const element = create();
    expect(element.find('button').length).toBe(1);
  });

  it("external expression should be defined", () => {
    const spy = jasmine.createSpy('spy');
    scope.externalExpression = spy;
    expect(Object.keys(scope)).toContain('externalExpression');
  });

  it('external expression should be calling', () => {
    const spy = jasmine.createSpy('spy');
    scope.externalExpression = spy;
    validHTML = '<test-dir external-expression="externalExpression()"><test-div>';
   
    const element = create();

    expect(Object.keys(angular.element(element.find('button')).scope())).toContain('externalExpression');
    element.find('button').triggerHandler('click');
    expect(scope.externalExpression.calls.count()).toBe(1);
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.1.0/jasmine.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.1.0/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.1.0/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.1.0/boot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
on-click="externalExpression()"
```

Change to ng-click

Comment: Thank you. It did save my day